# Triggering login email after user()

Tags: soap-api, user, user-admin

Is there any way to cause the new user email to be sent after creating a force.com user through the API (user() )?   Or is the only way when creating through the UI and checking the send email checkbox?

Alernatively, ff you use the set password() call after creating the user,  when does the user create their secret question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to cause the new user email to be sent after creating a force.com user through the API (user() )?

Use the [EmailHeader](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_header_emailheader.htm).triggerUserEmail flag.

> Alernatively, ff you use the set password() call after creating the user, when does the user create their secret question?

They won't be prompted to until the next time they change their password or configure it in Setup manually.